# NullPointerException, jagged arrays

Tags: java, exception

When I want to refer to an array element outside the constructor, the program throws me `NullPointerException (location: function ratio)`

```
private int tabPascal[][];


Pascal(int n){
    int tabPascal [][]= new int[n+1][];

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        tabPascal[i] = new int[i+1];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < tabPascal.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<tabPascal[i].length; j++){

            tabPascal[i][j] = binomial(i,j);
            System.out.print(tabPascal[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

...

```
   public int ratio(int n, int k){

    return tabPascal[n][k];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your instance variable in your constructor. Hence it's never initialized.

```
private int tabPascal[][];


Pascal(int n){
    tabPascal = new int[n+1][];  
    ....
}
```